# What will happen to my sqlite database ten years from now in terms of capacity and query speed

Tags: sqlite

I have created a database with one single table (check the code bellow). I plan to insert 10 rows per minute, which is about 52 million rows in ten years from now.

My question is, what can I expect in terms of database capacity and how long it will take to execute select query. Of course, I know you can not provide me an absolute values, but if you can give me any tips on change/speed rates, traps etc. I would be very glad.

I need to tell you, there will be 10 different observations (this is why I will insert ten rows per minute).

```
create table if not exists my_table (
date_observation default current_timestamp,
observation_name text,
value_1 real(20),
value_1_name text,
value_2 real(20),
value_2_name text,
value_3 real(20),
value_3_name text);
```

Comment: You need to normalize your table design and add some proper indexes.

Comment: @juergen, How do you mean if may I ask? I am not a database guy.

Comment: If your column names contain numbers then you are doing something wrong. If you are more specific about your data, maybe we can help you with a better design.

Comment: From the looks of things, you need to read up on one to many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Database capacity exceeds known storage device capacity as per [Limits In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

The more pertinent paragraphs are :-

> **Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table**
>
> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is  2^64
>   (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable
>   since the maximum database size of 140 terabytes will be reached
>   first. A 140 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately
>   1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row
>   contains very little data.
>
> **Maximum Database Size**
>
> Every database consists of one or more "pages". Within a single
>   database, every page is the same size, but different database can have
>   page sizes that are powers of two between 512 and 65536, inclusive.
>   The maximum size of a database file is 2147483646 pages. At the
>   maximum page size of 65536 bytes, this translates into a maximum
>   database size of approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes, or 128
>   tebibytes, or 140,000 gigabytes or 128,000 gibibytes).
>
> This particular upper bound is untested since the developers do not
>   have access to hardware capable of reaching this limit. However, tests
>   do verify that SQLite behaves correctly and sanely when a database
>   reaches the maximum file size of the underlying filesystem (which is
>   usually much less than the maximum theoretical database size) and when
>   a database is unable to grow due to disk space exhaustion.

Speed determination has many aspects and is thus not a simple how fast will it go, like a car. The file system, the memory, optimisation are all factors that need to be taken into consideration. As such the answer is the same as the length of the anecdotal piece of string.

- Note 18446744073709551616 is if you utilise negative numbers otherwise the more frequently mentioned number of 9223372036854775807 is the limit (i.e a 64 bit signed integer)

  - To utilise negative rowid numbers and therefore the higher range you have to insert at least 1 negative value explicitly into a rowid or alias thereof as per *If no negative ROWID values are inserted explicitly, then automatically generated ROWID values will always be greater than zero.*